# Data archiving strategy for my grand-grand-children to read in ~100 years?

Tags: backup, filesystems, archiving

I'm working on a custom, self-hosted data archiving system with the aim of being **easily readable by my grand-grand-children in about a century**.

Today, it's such a joy to stumble upon a pictures box in the grandpa's attic and spend hours looking through them. Tomorrow, our children won't be able to do that. Pictures and more generally data is buried under layers and layers of abstraction. I want to design an archiving strategy that will, among other things, allow them to plug the drive and easily see what's inside.

**What filesystem should I be betting on to be still natively, cross-platform readable in a century if set up today?** exFAT seems a reasonable bet but I'd rather go not proprietary.

Or should I rather choose whatever suits me better today (xfs and so on) and **stick to the drive a manual with the tools needed to read it?**

I'm quite new to digital archiving so any resource will be useful.

Comment: If you'd have asked that question 30 years ago, the answer would have probably contained words like "floppy disk, SCSI, ATA"... & who can read those these days [assuming they even survived that long]? Who still has a CD drive in their computer? You'd do far better printing everything & putting it in a safe box.

Comment: The SCSI and ATA protocols are very much alive – only the electrical interface has changed, and converters for that are readily available.

Comment: @Tetsujin Good point. So I guess you'd be on the "whatever fs + manual" side. To be honest, you can easily read a floppy disk today (just searched for floppy USB readers on Amazon), CDs too. I don't hope it to be plug and play, but at least limit the software complications.

Comment: @grawity - well, I guess SCSI 'became' USB, PATA moved to SATA... but that's in only 20 years; I'd be seriously worried about having made my legacy on 5.25" floppy & now be hunting around for something to read it... or cassette, paper tape, punch-card, Winchester disk, Iomega Jaz... MO disk... ...

Comment: Further thoughts, as i honestly don't have an answer to this... would any magnetic medium survive that long? Would instead, something like an iPad be a better bet - all it would need, assuming it could retain the data in a powered-off state for that time, would be a voltage source similar to today's. 50/60Hz 100-240v AC. [Maybe the battery would need to be removed]

Comment: We can't predict the future.  20 years ago, if you ask if videocassette recorders or players wouldn't be manufactured in 2018, people would look at you like you were crazy.  If you asked 30 years ago, if video camera would be digital instead of working with 35/50 mm film, they wouldn't even know what you were talking about.  My point is we don't know how long data will actually last on mechanical and SSD devices.  You should be prepared to continuously migrate any solution you select.  We can't even predict if data mechanical can be stored for 100 years.

Comment: (continue) in most cases it's more about if you will even be able to read the data off the media. There are floppy disk sizes ( 5" as an example) where a reader no longer exist.  While SATA is backwards compatiable with each revision, currently, that might not be the case in 10 years.  If we switch to the next standard then legacy SATA ports will cease to exist just like ATA ports have ceased to exist (outside of external devices).

Comment: I am tempted to suggest a cloud archive. Some form of this will likely be around in 100 years, though it's debatable whether any of the current cloud hosts will be around then. The best you can hope to do is to create an archive using the latest technology and bequeath it with an enjoinder to keep it updated in an up-to-date medium.

Comment: Yeah, that had crossed my mind too - half the problems currently being faced by long-term archiving solutions is that periodically you need to update the storage medium/file formats etc

Comment: @Ramhound 5" floppy drives are still available on amazon and ebay and you can buy converters to usb ...

Comment: ...but will they still be working in another century? [That's apart from the complete dust-ball that will be the magnetic substrate by then ;)

Comment: @DavidPostill - I am not talking about those particular 5" floppy disk.  I am talking about a floppy disk contained in 5" of plastic.  This was more like the 3.5"  floppy, in a 5" form factor, trust me readers don't exist for it.  (might have also been a tape, I honestly forget, my point is still valid).

Comment: @Ramhound I don't remember any disks with a rigid 5" format. And there are non listed at [Disk / Disc – Museum Of Obsolete Media](http://www.obsoletemedia.org/data/disk/)